# $\sum p(x,y) \log p(x,y) = \sum p(x,y) \log p(x)p(y)$ (zero mutual information) implies independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, summation, expectation

Let $(X,Y)$ be jointly distributed with probability mass function $p(x,y)$. What can be concluded if $\sum p(x,y) \log p(x,y) = \sum p(x,y) \log p(x)p(y)$? I thought about using Jensens inequality but that led to nothing.

Note that $\sum p(x,y) = 1$ are probabilities and we don't know wether $X$ and $Y$ are dependent or not.

Comment: The equality LHS $=$ RHS doesn't hold. Maybe you want to prove LHS $\ge$ RHS?

Comment: Initially I wanted to show that $I(X;Y) = 0 \rightarrow X$ and $Y$ are independent. Then I just plugged in the formula for mutual information and came to that conclusion.

Comment: Mutual information is defined as the KL divergence between $P(x)p(y)$ and $P(x,y)$, which is bigger or equal to zero by [Jensen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#:~:text=(2)-,equality%20holds%20if%20and%20only%20if%20,-x%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20x). See Jensen's equality conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the mutual information between $X$ and $Y$ is zero, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Here's a proof:

Define $$g(x,y):=\frac{p(x)p(y)}{p(x,y)}.$$
With this definition we have
$$\sum p(x,y)g(x,y) = \sum p(x)p(y)=1,\tag1$$
where the sum is taken over all possible $(x,y)$ pairs. If the claimed equality holds, then
$$
\begin{align}
0&=0 - \sum p(x,y)\log g(x,y)\\
&\stackrel{(1)}=\sum p(x,y)g(x,y) - 1 - \sum p(x,y)\log g(x,y)\\
&=\sum p(x,y)\left [g(x,y)-1 - \log g(x,y)\right]\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Note that the bracketed quantity in (2) is nonnegative (since $\log t\le t-1$ for all $t$), so (2) is a sum of nonnegative terms. If the sum is in fact zero, then the bracketed quantity is identically zero:
$$
\log g(x,y) = g(x,y) -1\quad\text{for all $x,y$}
$$
But $t=1$ is the only value of $t$ for which $\log t=t-1$. This implies $$g(x,y)=1 \quad\text{for all $x,y$},$$ i.e., $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have 2 questions: 1) How can you say that $\sum p(x) p(y) = 1$? 2) Is the term $[g(x,y) - 1 - log g(x,y)$ inside or outside the sum?

Comment: @今天春天 (1) The sum over $(x,y)$ can be written as the double sum $\sum_x\sum_y$. (2) The bracketed quantity is inside the sum.

Comment: (1) Am I right here that we're not assuming anything regarding joint distribution? Because In every distribution, no matter how it looks, the sum of probabilities is 1? Otherwise, it is not a probability distribution.

Comment: @今天春天 Yes, no assumption about the joint distribution is being made. I am writhing $p(x)$ as shorthand for the marginal distribution of $X$ and $p(y)$ for the marginal distribution of $Y$. You should read $p(x)$ as $p_X(x)$, etc.

Comment: @今天春天 ... so $\sum_{x,y}p(x)p(y)=\sum_xp(x)\sum_yp(y)=1\cdot1$

Comment: Thank you. This helped alot.